# Same method opening again in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have written a method in JSF managed bean for exporting a table to excel. This method is working fine when called, the problem is after calling this method, if any other method is called this export method is only getting called.

This is my export to excel method

```
public void exportHtmlTableToExcel() throws IOException {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context
                .getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment;filename=csopdetails.xls");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        try {

            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

//Code here

}

 wb.write(response.getOutputStream());

            // wb.write();
            // os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // Handle exception ...
        }
```

Can any one help me on sorting this issue.

Comment: Can you share your method and also show, which method when called is re-invoking the method.

Comment: Is there anything to be given at the end of the method to clear the session.?

Comment: Any reason why you want to clear the session ?

Comment: Because the same method is being invoked again, even after any other method is called.?

Comment: So the file is being downloaded twice?

Comment: Yes.. After clicking any method, this method is only getting opened.

Comment: maybe you have to put this line of code at end of the method:
`context.responseComplete()`